# Python перезагрузить сервис tor

Tags: python, tor

Добрый день. Уже голову себе сломал с вопросом "перезагрузить сервис tor" с помощью python. Я это пытался делать вот так:

```
subprocess.Popen('/etc/init.d/tor restart', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

и вот так

```
subprocess.Popen('service tor restart', shell=True)
```

Вроде как процесс перезагрузки происходит, но не появляются в каталоге настроек домена tor файл `hostname` и `private_key`. Если я произвожу сам команду `service tor restart` через консоль - файлы появляются. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Питон от рута запускаете хоть? Питон дожидается завершения выполненной команды?

Comment: От рута. Да, стоит wait()

Comment: Что очень занимательно, если запустить python и вводить команды там - то работает. Как это вообще происходит

Answer (score 0):

Я использую такой код (был стянут откуда-то с github, но уже не помню откуда).

```
from commands import getoutput
from subprocess import call, check_call, CalledProcessError
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError
from os import devnull
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout, stderr


def restart_tor():
      fnull = open(devnull, 'w')
      try:
        tor_restart = check_call(
            ["service", "tor", "restart"],
              stdout=fnull, stderr=fnull)

        if tor_restart is 0:
          print(" {0}".format(
              "[\033[92m+\033[0m] Anonymizer status \033[92m[ON]\033[0m"))
          print(" {0}".format(
              "[\033[92m*\033[0m] Getting public IP, please wait..."))
          retries = 0
          my_public_ip = None
          while retries < 12 and not my_public_ip:
            retries += 1
            try:
              my_public_ip = load(urlopen('http://jsonip.com/'))['ip']
            except URLError:
              sleep(5)
              print(" [\033[93m?\033[0m] Still waiting for IP address...")
          print
          if not my_public_ip:
            my_public_ip = getoutput('wget -qO - v4.ifconfig.co')
          if not my_public_ip:
            exit(" \033[91m[!]\033[0m Can't get public ip address!")
          print(" {0}".format("[\033[92m+\033[0m] Your IP is \033[92m%s\033[0m" % my_public_ip))
      except CalledProcessError as err:
        print("\033[91m[!] Command failed: %s\033[0m" % ' '.join(err.cmd))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
        restart_tor()
```